# "Help + noun/pronoun+ to verb, to verb, verb " or "Help + noun/pronoun+ to verb, verb, verb "

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

> *The United States has provided billions of dollars to help
>   them train more teachers, to modernize
>   transportation, to improve health care, to promote the
>   rights of workers and women, and produce food more
>   efficiently*.

Look at this sentence - According to the rule the writer has used bare infinitive before (train) but why she used (to) infinitive for others serial comma.And again she has chosen bare infinitive before (produce). I am confused.

What if I write:

The United States has provided billions of dollars to help
them train more teachers, modernize
transportation, improve health care, promote the
rights of workers and women, and produce food more
efficiently.

Does it sound bad?

Comment: You can use either a bare or a to-infinitive after help

Comment: Your sentence sounds fine, @dz420, but the original sounds better. _Help_ can take the bare or the to-infinitive as the writer chooses. The writer here made a stylistic choice based on the rhythm of the sentence: based on the way it sounds.